# ymaps sdk плейсмарк уезжает

Tags: java, android, яндекс-карта-api

у меня возник такой вопрос.

Пишу стриминговую площадку по местоположению автомобилей, возникла проблема

Есть плейсмарки, которые стоят фиксировано, т.е при уменьшении-увеличении карты они стоят на месте, а есть плейсмарки которые при уменьшении/увеличении карты уезжают. Как можно от этого избавится и зафиксировать их?

Уже пробовал скайл ставивть на 0, все равно уезжает, тут показано
Удалял вообще строку со стилями, тоже уезжает
пишу на джаве

пример кода с фиксированным плейсмарком

```
PlacemarkMapObject end = mapObjects.addPlacemark(p2, ImageProvider.fromResource(HomeActivity.this, R.drawable.end));
```

```
PlacemarkMapObject mY = mapObjects.addPlacemark(cars, ImageProvider.fromResource(HomeActivity.this, R.drawable.car_yellow_small));
m.setIconStyle(new IconStyle().setAnchor(new PointF(0f, 0f)).setRotationType(RotationType.ROTATE).setZIndex(0f).setScale(0f));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Странно, почему этому вопросу поставили -1, ну ладно.

Решение простое - из за анчора

Т.е в стилях при удалении метода `setAnchor()` все прошло

Строки стали выглядеть так:

```
PlacemarkMapObject mY = mapObjects.addPlacemark(cars, ImageProvider.fromResource(HomeActivity.this, R.drawable.car_yellow_small));
mY.setIconStyle(new IconStyle().setRotationType(RotationType.ROTATE));
```